# Java EE - Need 2 response.addCokie() method to actually set a cookie

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies

I'm learning Java EE and cookies and I'm trying to set a cookie. My problem is that I need to send a GET request twice to actually set the cookie.I tried to set it twice in doGet() method without any conditions, then I checked the result on PostMan and it worked, the cookie was set with a single request.

I can't manage to understand my problem, that's why I'm asking for your kind help.

I'm working on a Tomvat v7 server.

```
//Won't work
protected void doGet(...){
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie", "value");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}

//Will work
protected void doGet(...){
    Cookie cokie = new Cookie("cookie", "value");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    response.addCokkie(cookie);
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Arthur